# Rails mountable engine under a dynamic scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

say that I have these routes:

```
scope '(:locale)', :locale => /en|de/ do
  mount Users::Engine => "users", as: 'users_engine'  
end
```

and in engine's view:

```
<%= link_to 'new user', action: :new, controller: :users, locale: :de %>
```

I get

```
/en/users/users/new?locale=de
```

instead of

```
/de/users/users/new
```

I have already included in application controller:

```
def set_locale
  if params.include?('locale')
    I18n.locale = params[:locale]
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:locale] = I18n.locale
  end
end
```

and it works fine in the main app

I have found a way to get the right url by

```
Users::Engine.routes.url_for controller: 'users/users', action: :new, only_path: true, locale: :de
```

but I think that there should be a better way and what if I was making a change-locale link in the layout ?

```
<%= link_to locale: :de %>
```

I cannot know which exact engine this could be

Thanks vm.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003626/i18n-routing-to-mounted-engine-ignoring-locale/18150942

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution for that...

Just use the url_options-method in your application_controller.rb-File (see link below)

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18299975/603126

Hope it helps!

Regards

Philipp