# Setting default_url_options for mounted Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, rails-engines

Using rails 3.2.13 and spree 2.0.2
I've encountered the similar problem as in [Rails mountable engine under a dynamic scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14875404/159721)

My routes:

```
scope ':locale', locale: /en|jp/ do
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/store'
  root to: 'home#index'
end
```

I want to output link to change locale:

```
<%= link_to 'JP', url_for(locale: :jp) %>
```

but this outputs:

```
<a href="/en/store/?locale=jp">JP</a>
```

instead of expected:

```
<a href="/jp/store">JP</a>
```

**-- Edit --**

When I put to `ApplicationController`:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

it sets locale params in store twice instead of merging them:

```
http://localhost:3000/en/store/products/bag?locale=en
```

Comment: Do you had any luck to solve your problem?
Cause I have the same problem as you at the moment.
Thanks in advance

Comment: No. _Please upvote for visibility_.

Comment: I hope it will help! ;-)

Comment: Solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003626/i18n-routing-to-mounted-engine-ignoring-locale/18150942

Answer (score 1):

Faced exactly the same problem and I have found a solution for that...

Here is my application_controller-File (my engines inherit from this file (which is the Main Apps ApplicationController, so that I don't have code-duplication)

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :set_locale_from_params

  def url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end

  protected
    def set_locale_from_params
      if params[:locale]
        if I18n.available_locales.include?(params[:locale].to_sym)
          I18n.locale = params[:locale]
        else
          flash.now[:notice] = 'Translation not available'
          logger.error flash.now[:notice]
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Note, that the url_options-code is outside the protected part. It has to be public.

Found the tipps for the solution here:
[default_url_options and rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100954/default-url-options-and-rails-3)

Hope it helps

Regards

Philipp

Comment: for some reason I was only experiencing this problem in my specs, and this helped, I just changed to

`before_filter :set_locale_from_params, if: Rails.env == "test"`

Answer (score 1):

To set the default_url_options for an engine like Spree. You need to target the engine and set the parameter.

For example, to set the **host**.

```rb
    # config/environment/development.rb
 
    Spree::Core::Engine.routes.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```